# Angular 5 - How to load certain css styles on certain routes (bootstrap css only for admin routes)

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-router

I need bootstrap css only on routes that begin with '/admin', i've lazyloading for admin and public modules.

Comment: if there are dynamically generated content, then styles for that particular component may not work, as styles are also applied through virtual DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make below child routes for admin components

```
 export const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
      { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent,children: [
    { path: '/user', component: AdminUserComponent }
    ]}
    ];
```

Comment: this way styles are will be loaded everywhere, for example when i go to '/home' styles will be available, i don't want this behaviour.

Comment: @ppl, how to load css style ?

Answer (score 0):

the easier way is to manually link the style using styleUrls for your admin component.

admin.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

admin.component.css

```
/*!
* Bootstrap v4.0.0 (https://getbootstrap.com)
* Copyright 2011-2018 The Bootstrap Authors
* Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc.
* Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
*/
:root {
    --blue: #007bff;
    --indigo: #6610f2;
    --purple: #6f42c1;
    --pink: #e83e8c;
    --red: #dc3545;
    --orange: #fd7e14;
    --yellow: #ffc107;
    --green: #28a745;
    --teal: #20c997;
    --cyan: #17a2b8;
    --white: #fff;
    --gray: #6c757d;
    --gray-dark: #343a40;
    --primary: #007bff;
    --secondary: #6c757d;
    --success: #28a745;
    --info: #17a2b8;
    --warning: #ffc107;
    --danger: #dc3545;
    --light: #f8f9fa;
    --dark: #343a40;
    --breakpoint-xs: 0;
    --breakpoint-sm: 576px;
    --breakpoint-md: 768px;
    --breakpoint-lg: 992px;
    --breakpoint-xl: 1200px;
    --font-family-sans-serif: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
    --font-family-monospace: SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
}
/* ..... rest of bootstrap.css */
```

Comment: This is tagged for Bootstrap 4, so you might want to take that into consideration. Of course in this example it doesn't matter that much.

Comment: I only want to give an example, anyway I've changed it to Bootstrap 4

Comment: This will work, but for every component in the admin section i'll have to add it manually, i was thinking more in a way to set it it up on start and forget about it :)
Thanks anyway